# Webpack - reference most recent build in html

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, webpack, webpack-2

I'm trying to hash my builds in webpack like so:

```
module.exports = {

    // ....

    output: {
        path: './bin',
        filename: 'app.bundle.[hash:6].js',
        publicPath: '/bin/'
    },

    // ....

}
```

So when I bundle with webpack, I get something like this in the command line:

```
Hash: c2d3b2003d64b88b4438
Version: webpack 2.2.1
Time: 689ms
                   Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    app.bundle.c2d3b2.js  385 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
app.bundle.c2d3b2.js.map  570 kB       0  [emitted]         main
```

So I know it is hashing properly. My question is, how do I reference the latest webpack hash in html? Right now, I have:

```
<script src="bin/app.bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

But I can't just do:

```
<script src="bin/app.bundle[hash:6].js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin). It generates an HTML file that automatically includes all the bundles generated by webpack. If you use [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin), the extracted CSS files will also be included in the HTML. You can use a custom [template](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates) if you don't want to use the default one.

Example with `template.html` as template (the default output file is `index.html`):

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'template.html'
  })
]
```

Comment: I just want to replace app.bundle.js with app.bundle.c2d3b2.js depending on the most recent hash. How will this help me? This seems like it generates new html files.

Comment: It does generate a new HTML each time you run webpack, but it gets replaced with every build. There is not really any difference with editing the file every time. Just point it to the correct location. The [`filename` option](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#configuration) accepts a path.

Comment: Ok, but how do I get the html to point to my latest webpack build?

Comment: The generated HTML will automatically include the bundles (with their hashes). No further setup needed.

Comment: You're saying that if I load with html-webpack-plugin, I can simply delete this line: `<script src="bin/app.bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`? Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I created a [minimal example](https://github.com/jungomi/minimal-html-webpack-plugin-example), so you can see how it works. You might also be interested in reading [Using the HTML Webpack Plugin for generating HTML files](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2016/07/webpack-html-plugin/).